# How do I do palindromes in java?

Tags: java

First time posting here! Yeah I kind of just need some help with this assignment. We had to read an input file, go through a loop for each character in a line of the input file, and store that info in a char array, and then finally write an isPalindrome method and call it to determine if that line is a palindrome and print it to the console.

This is what I have so far, sorry if I didn't format correctly, it was kind of confusing.
I'm still kind of a beginner and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. My output is essentially "[C@91bee48 is not a palindrome!" over and over again with some variation on whether or not its a palindrome.

```
public class Palindromes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 0;

        try {
          Scanner inF = new Scanner(new File("palindromes.txt"));
          String aString;
          while (inF.hasNextLine()) {
            aString = inF.nextLine();
            k++;
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
              char[] phrases = new char[aString.length()];
              if (Character.isLetter(aString.charAt(k))) {
                phrases[i] = aString.charAt(i);
              }
              isPalindrome(phrases);
            }
          }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.err.println("palindromes.txt not found!");
        }
    }


    public static void isPalindrome(char[] phrases) {
        boolean isPalindrome = false;
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = phrases.length - 1;
        while (i2 > i1) {
          if (phrases[i1] != phrases[i2]) {
            isPalindrome = false;
            System.out.println(phrases + " is not a palindrome!");
          } else {
            isPalindrome = true;
            System.out.println(phrases + " is a palindrome!");
          }
          i1++;
          i2--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use an array directly in `System.out.println`; that's why you're getting the weird `[C@91bee48` in the output.  Replace `phrases` with `new String(phrases)`, which will convert the `char[]` to a `String`.

Comment: @Makoto I don't think it's a duplicate, because there are other problems besides the `toString` problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29) to get the string representing the array.

For example:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(phrases) + " is not a palindrome!");
```

Otherwise you get the default `toString()` for an array object - which is not what you are after.

Comment: This is a `char[]` he's trying to print.  `Arrays.toString` will return something like `"[H, e, l, l, o]"` instead of `"Hello"`.  `new String(phrases)` will return `"Hello"`.  But best would be to restructure the code or at least to pass the original `String` to the method, because it shouldn't be necessary to reconstruct a `String` that the program already has possession of.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your `while` loop is faulty.  This kind of loop is a common idiom: you have to check a number of things, and if any check fails, you want the result to be `false`.  If no check fails, you want the result to be `true`.  The thing is, you can't tell if the result is `true` until the loop is completely finished.  Your code is:

```
while (i2 > i1)
{
    if(phrases[i1] != phrases[i2])
    {
        isPalindrome = false;
        System.out.println(phrases + " is not a palindrome!");
    }
    else
    {
        isPalindrome = true;
        System.out.println(phrases + " is a palindrome!");
    }
    i1++;
    i2--;
}
```

The problem is that you're printing `"is a palindrome"` before you've checked all the characters, and you can't possibly know that.  The way to write this kind of loop is something like this:

```
isPalindrome = true;
while (i2 > i1)
{
    if(phrases[i1] != phrases[i2])
    {
        isPalindrome = false;
        break;  // get out of the loop, it's pointless to continue
    }
    i1++;
    i2--;
}
// *** NOW you can check isPalindrome and display your output
```